# Как правильно  -- host:port/tcp или host:tcp/port в параметрах командной строки или конфиге?

Tags: c, linux, сеть

Понятно, что в 99.9% используется запись

```
 host:port
```

(точнее, конечно, не порт, а сервис, например, `echo`, а не 7), сам искал, искал, но ни ответа, ни даже примеров за полчаса  не нашел.

В /etc/services сначала порт, потом протокол, а вот один коллега сказал, что в командах cisco пишут host:proto/service...

Итак, все же, **как принято писать в общем виде?**

(Разбор варианта `host:service/proto` программируется, по крайней мере при вызове `getservbyname()` короче).

Comment: используйте  URI :)

например, для http over udp [рекомендуют](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-goland-http-udp-01) делать что-то типа такого:

     httpu://example.com:port/path?query

Comment: Не..., не то. 

URI это уже другой стиль.

Comment: так а куда вставлять ? я чаще всего видел отдельные опции для proto/host/port т.е. что-то типа

   program -p 80 --udp example.com

а когда одной строкой, то URI вообще если вы пишите утилиту какую-то посмотрите на те утилиты с которыми возможно вашу будут стыковать и сделайте так-же.

Comment: @eicto, в URI слово в начале -- `http:`, `ftp:` и т.п. называется *схема* и явно не задает *сетевой протокол* (tcp/udp/icmp/...).

Если подходить серьезно, то схема вообще-то задает правила интерпретации всего остатка адреса (т.е. он является контекстозависимым).

--

Мне же хочется на основе одного аргумента заполнить структуру IPv4 адреса (`struct sockaddr_in`). Поэтому URI это совсем не то.

Запись `host:port` в общем-то достаточно распространенная в \*nix утилитах. Просто хочется предоставить возможность добавлять еще и протокол (вместо NULL) при вызове `getservbyname()`.

Comment: @avp а чем протокол не схема ? и чем http не протокол ? :) ну я вас понимаю, просто если вас интересуют пожелания сисадминов я их высказываю - либо UR[IN] либо так как сделано в утилитах того-же класса, host:port я не припомню в базовых утилитах, может и есть.

еще вот так бывает (bash)

    /dev/udp/host/port

Comment: @eicto, ну, раз и здесь никто не может припомнить, то будем считать вопрос решенным -- **`host:service/proto`**.

Имеется в виду `sevice` из `/etc/services` и `proto` из `/etc/protocols`.

Comment: в cmdline такого я никогда не видел

Answer (score 2):

Общепринятая полная запись сервиса **service-name port/protocol**,
т.е. для вашего вопроса ответ такой: **host:port/protocol**

Comment: OK. Именно это я и сделал, отметив это в своем комментарии от 12.08.2014